# Confused about html parsing in flutter

Tags: flutter, html-parsing

If i run this cod in the browser  [like this way](https://www.hizliresim.com/qsnl28a)

```
 document.querySelectorAll("div.swiper-container ul.product-grid  li.swiper-slide").length.toString();
```

It retuns 8

The problem is that -If I run this code in android stuido

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Future getData()async{

    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://www.kitapyurdu.com');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var document = parse(response.body);


   var v= document.querySelectorAll("div.swiper-container ul.product-grid  li.swiper-slide").length;
print(v.toString());


  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
getData();

    return Container();
  }
}
```

then It returns 0

What is wrong here I am using http and html packages

Edit:Or is there anaother way to  do this

Comment: Are you sure response.body contains what you think it contains when accessed from the core-http package?  You have a pretty specific query string.

Comment: I think you are right.How can it be possible.And what is your suggestion plase

Comment: I don't know the possible variation of responses, so I don't know how "loose" you have to make the matching.